# Erlang SDK - IntelliJ - Centos 7

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, erlang, centos7

- I am trying to make an OpenIMS server with this tutorial:http://www.openimscore.org/documentation/installation-guide/
- I am using CentOS 7, got erlang installed by verifying command "erl" in terminal
- Then I tried following this tutorial to start my own coding: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/getting-started-with-erlang.html
- but I cannot run the erlang project by IntelliJ because of the error: "can't find include lib "diameter/include/diameter_gen_base_cxdx.hrl".
- I found nothing inside the folder "/usr/local/lib/erlang".
- I think the problem is about missing Erlang-SDK installed for IntelliJ

Does anyone know how to configure the Erlang SDK for IntelliJ on  Centos 7 please?
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: The project description contains the word `diameter` several times, so I think the file `diameter/include/diameter_gen_base_cxdx.hrl` should probably be in the source code for the project somewhere.

Comment: thank you, I found out that the point is about the diamter lib:
    - The libs inside "/usr/local/lib/erlang" is refreshed every time we build the project
    - What we should do is to copy the erlang libs to where you install the otp/Open-IMS.